# How to embed my facebook fanpage wall in my iframe tab?

Tags: facebook

I'm quite new to facebook.
I'd like to have an i-frame tab on my facebook fanpage  with the wall embedded on the same tab as the example: http://www.facebook.com/avrillavigne?sk=app_178091127385

I have searched for it but haven't found how exactly I can do this.

Do I need the Graph API, Java SDK or PHP SDK to do this?
Are there any examples?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can't just "embed" a Facebook page inside your app, you need to retrieve the [Page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/)'s feeds through the Graph API or just use the [Like Box](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/).

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the Feed using the Graph API. 
Here is the initial documentation on how to use it: 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/

This second link might not work when you click on it, but if you go to the examples on the first link and  use the news feed example from the second list you can swap out "me/feed" for "your_page/feed" and get the feed.

With that you just need to format it so it looks like the wall.

https://graph.facebook.com/cocacola/feed?access_token=2227470867|2.AQBnDvmcD3XoWI_F.3600.1316984400.0-515157640|hp7gwy_E3M9wLtyhBPxrsobi__E

Comment: So, there is no easy way to do this? The only way is use Graph API and manually format it? Since from the example I saw at http://www.facebook.com/avrillavigne?sk=app_178091127385 is really like a normal wall.